# WordPress paginate_links - how to use it?

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-4.5.2

I want to add a numberic pagination to a page with its child pages. This is the pagination I would want to create (from bootstrap):

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And this is my code:

```
<!-- block -->
<div class="row grid events-block">

    <?php
    $parent = $post->ID;
    // query_posts('posts_per_page=15&post_type=page&post_parent='.$parent);
    query_posts(array('posts_per_page'=>'1', 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => $parent, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged')));
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>

    <!-- item -->
    <div class="grid-item col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 event-item">

        <div class="date-box">
            <?php echo $event_dates; ?>
        </div>

        <div class="event-item-text-box">
            <div class="event-item-text-inner-box">
                <h3 class="heading-item"><a href="#" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- item -->
     <?php endwhile; ?>

     <?php
     // Reset the post to the original after loop. otherwise the current page becomes the last item from the while loop.
     // https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query
     wp_reset_query();
     ?>

</div>
<!-- block -->

<?php $args = array(
    'base'               => '%_%',
    'format'             => '?paged=%#%',
    'total'              => 1,
    'current'            => 0,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'end_size'           => 1,
    'mid_size'           => 2,
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'          => __('Next »'),
    'type'               => 'plain',
    'add_args'           => false,
    'add_fragment'       => '',
    'before_page_number' => '',
    'after_page_number'  => ''
); ?>

<?php echo paginate_links( $args ); ?>
```

But I can't get it working. Any ideas what I have missed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> **Pagination Like : Prev 1 2 3 Next**

```
<?php 
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$data= new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'=>'YOUR_POST_TYPE', // your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 3, // post per page
    'paged' => $paged,
));

if($data->have_posts()) :
    while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post();
            // Your code
    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }
    ?>    
<?php else :?>
<h3><?php _e('404 Error&#58; Not Found', ''); ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Could you please try above code? I think it's helpful for you.

Comment: @purvik7373 how can i separate the navigation? So i can put a navigation bar outside the loop? And it's still hooked up to the dashboard settings page. Because when i use 3 in the code and have 5 in the Dashboards settings then the navigation  shows the pages right but when there are only 10 posts and i go to page 3 then that page is empty. When i change the 5 in 3 (so the same als in de code) then it is working correctly. So what is going wrong?

Comment: Hi! Very good your tip, can you help me with a question? How can I adjust the url to change the pages, because as the site is different it goes from 404 error.

Comment: @zecaluis Might be its permalink issue, please save your permalink with post name.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function to have a lovely bootstrap paginated links.

```
function bootstrap_pagination()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $big = 999999999;
    $listString = paginate_links(array(
        'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
        'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
        'prev_text'    => __('← Previous'),
        'next_text'    => __('Next  →'),
        'type'  => 'list',

    ));
    
    $listString = str_replace("<ul class='page-numbers'>", '<ul class="pagination">', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace('page-numbers', 'page-link', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace('<li>', '<li class="page-item">', $listString);
    $listString = str_replace(
        '<li class="page-item"><span aria-current="page" class="page-link current">',
        '<li class="page-item active"><span aria-current="page" class="page-link">',
        $listString
    );


    echo $listString;

}
```