# How to include pagination in a Wordpress Custom Post Type Query

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have the code below:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=30&post_type=phcl' ); ?>

<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-xs-12 file">
    <a href="<?php echo $file; ?>" class="file-title" target="_blank">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
        <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
    </a>
    <div class="file-description">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I am trying to use `paginate_links` Wordpress function but no matter where I put it, I can't make it work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>30,
                                 'post_type'=>'phcl',
                                 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) 
                            ); 
                            ?>
<?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 file">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="file-title" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
</a>
<div class="file-description"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
 echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Use <?php the_permalink(); ?> in place of <?php echo $file; ?>

Comment: There's a small error in this solution. The code 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1) should not have a final parenthesis. In order for the pagination to run correctly remove the closing parenthesis from after the number 1.

Comment: query for pagination doesn't work, when i click the second page t returns the first page posts

Comment: @Jay no it didnt

Answer (score 21):

When querying a loop with new [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query) set the 'total' parameter to the `max_num_pages` property of the `WP_Query` object.

**Example of a custom query:**

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array(
    'post_type'=>'post', // Your post type name
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => $paged,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

             // YOUR CODE

    endwhile;

    $total_pages = $loop->max_num_pages;

    if ($total_pages > 1){

        $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));

        echo paginate_links(array(
            'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
            'format' => '/page/%#%',
            'current' => $current_page,
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
            'next_text'    => __('next »'),
        ));
    }    
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Example of `paginate_links` parameters adapted to the custom query above:

For more reference please visit this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38939212/wordpress-paginate-links-how-to-use-it/38939382#38939382)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. It does show me the pagination. But when I click on the URL for Page 2, it still shows me the same content as Page 1. Any ideas?

Comment: @KhomNazid You are following this permalink structure https://www.screencast.com/t/IeYH7bxY3 Right?

Comment: @PurvikDhorajiya, no. I'm following `%category%/%postname%`, which we do need for our blog section outside the custom posts. For custom posts, we rely on the "Permalink Manager Lite" plugin. Our specific case is detailed here (and now our page 2 gives a 404, actually): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57301662/wordpress-pagination-issues-with-custom-post-type-and-custom-rewrite-rule

Comment: This is perfect!! @PurvikDhorajiya

Comment: This works well for me thank you, however, it always takes you to the top of the page like you are navigating between different pages, where as  I would like it to stay in the same position and just appear to paginate through the post section. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
      Try This one, it worked for  me!
    
    <?php
                 $paged = get_query_var('paged');
                    
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'blogs',
                    'paged' => $paged,
                    'orderby' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                    while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
                        $the_query->the_post();   
            ?>


             Your code...
        <?php
                        }

                    }
                   
     wp_reset_query();
  ?>

<div class="pagination">
<?php
                echo "<div class='fz-pagination'>" . paginate_links(array(
                    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
                    'prev_text' => __('<div class="preious-page">Prev</div>'),
                    'next_text' => __('<div class="next-page">Next</div>')
                )) . "</div>";
            ?>
</div>
```