# pagination numeric Custom post types wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Anyone know how I can put numerical paging using custom post types in wordpress?

```
$posts_per_page = 10;
$post_type = 'products'

$args = array( 'post_type'=> $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') );

query_posts( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array( 'post_type'=> $post_type, 'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page, 'paged' => get_query_var('paged') );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args);
 //Your post loop goes here...
 //Get the posts and show your post datas however you want;
```

Once you are done getting the posts, try the below code for pagination

```
 $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

 echo paginate_links( array(
 'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
 'format' => '?paged=%#%',
 'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
 'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages
 ) );

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Similar solution can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41738362/how-to-include-pagination-in-a-wordpress-custom-post-type-query/41738501#41738501)